# Google Tag Manager - Universal Analytics tag - uid parameter

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How to use Universal Analytics Tag and set "uid" field in Google Tag Manager? (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#uid)

I've found some information about this by this links:

https://www.optimizesmart.com/cross-device-tracking-with-user-id-in-google-tag-manager/

http://dan-russell.com/2014/06/help-i-just-enabled-the-user-id-feature-through-google-tag-manager-and-my-pageviews-dropped/

But neither "userId" nor "&uid" nor "uid" fields seems to be not working in GTM v5. (I've watched http trafic for google analytics in sniffer):

[image: Event network data]

Here is my GTM configuration [image: tag configuration]

P.S. I use GTM for Android

Comment: `userId` should work. Did you remember to enable the feature in GA, under the Property Settings > Tracking Info > User-ID?

Comment: @nyuen Yes I enabled User-ID and updated field name to "userId" in container. I also updated container in my android app. There is no uid parameter in http trafic and no data in User-ID view.

Comment: Refused of using GTM because of this. Returned to using old-good GoogleAnalytics tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I remember facing a similar issue last year. It looks like your configuration is correct. However the userId feature in GA only work with the view activated with it.

Consequently, I ended up adding the userId as a custom dimension as well in order to be able to get the information in all the views.

NB: I highly recommend to install the GA debugger for Chrome. It allows you to see exactly what information is sent straight from the console.

Hope it helps.

A.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

Your implementation is almost right, but you must use **userId** instead of **&uid**.

Using the **userId** as the field to set, the tag will send the data as **&uid** automaticaly.

---

[Here is the guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference?hl=en#userId) for further reading and other fields you might need to set.

Good tracking!

Comment: I tried userId. It's not working with android GTM sdk.